# Invalid distance calculation using Haversine formula

Tags: java, sqlite, haversine

**DISCLAIMER**
This is a hometask. Please, don't take it serious or think about this problem for more than 2 seconds. It's just not worth it. I'm sorry.

I am trying to calculate the approximate distance of the route. In the getPoints method I am requesting all the route points from the database and writing them into the array. This part works well and as expected. Here you can see the code snippet:

```
public ArrayList<Double> getPoints() {
    ArrayList<Double> location = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select latitude,longitude from " + Table_Name_Location, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Double latitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Lat"));
            Double longitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Longi"));
            location.add(latitude);
            location.add(longitude);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return location;
}

private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double theta = lon1 - lon2;
    double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1))
            * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2))
            + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1))
            * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2))
            * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = rad2deg(dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    return (dist);
}

private double deg2rad(double deg) {
    return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

private double rad2deg(double rad) {
    return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

However, when the time comes to the calculating the distance itself the problem occurs. For some reason the Haversine formula calculates the distances incorrectly. I recon, that the problem somewhere in the distance method, but cannot identify it myself. I've compared my implementation of Haversine formula, but haven’t found any differences with the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *[Android SDK](https://source.android.com/)* includes a *[Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location)* class, which computes the *[Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)*.

Here is the source code.

- *[Google – java/android/location/Location.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/Location.java)*
- *[Android Code Search – Location.java](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/location/java/android/location/Location.java;l=1?q=Location.java)*

The method is titled, *"distanceBetween"*, and utilizes a *private* *"computeDistanceAndBearing"* method.
And, the computed values are, distance in meters, initial bearing, and final bearing.

Here is a ported version.
I've removed the *BearingDistanceCache* argument, and adjusted it to return a *double array*.

```java
double[] computeDistanceAndBearing(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    // Based on http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf
    // using the "Inverse Formula" (section 4)

    // Convert lat/long to radians
    lat1 *= Math.PI / 180.0;
    lat2 *= Math.PI / 180.0;
    lon1 *= Math.PI / 180.0;
    lon2 *= Math.PI / 180.0;

    double a = 6378137.0; // WGS84 major axis
    double b = 6356752.3142; // WGS84 semi-major axis
    double f = (a - b) / a;
    double aSqMinusBSqOverBSq = (a * a - b * b) / (b * b);

    double l = lon2 - lon1;
    double aA = 0.0;
    double u1 = Math.atan((1.0 - f) * Math.tan(lat1));
    double u2 = Math.atan((1.0 - f) * Math.tan(lat2));

    double cosU1 = Math.cos(u1);
    double cosU2 = Math.cos(u2);
    double sinU1 = Math.sin(u1);
    double sinU2 = Math.sin(u2);
    double cosU1cosU2 = cosU1 * cosU2;
    double sinU1sinU2 = sinU1 * sinU2;

    double sigma = 0.0;
    double deltaSigma = 0.0;
    double cosSqAlpha;
    double cos2SM;
    double cosSigma;
    double sinSigma;
    double cosLambda = 0.0;
    double sinLambda = 0.0;

    double lambda = l; // initial guess
    for (int iter = 0; iter < 20; iter++) {
        double lambdaOrig = lambda;
        cosLambda = Math.cos(lambda);
        sinLambda = Math.sin(lambda);
        double t1 = cosU2 * sinLambda;
        double t2 = cosU1 * sinU2 - sinU1 * cosU2 * cosLambda;
        double sinSqSigma = t1 * t1 + t2 * t2;
        sinSigma = Math.sqrt(sinSqSigma);
        cosSigma = sinU1sinU2 + cosU1cosU2 * cosLambda;
        sigma = Math.atan2(sinSigma, cosSigma);
        double sinAlpha = (sinSigma == 0) ? 0.0 :
            cosU1cosU2 * sinLambda / sinSigma;
        cosSqAlpha = 1.0 - sinAlpha * sinAlpha;
        cos2SM = (cosSqAlpha == 0) ? 0.0 : cosSigma - 2.0 * sinU1sinU2 / cosSqAlpha;

        double uSquared = cosSqAlpha * aSqMinusBSqOverBSq;
        aA = 1 + (uSquared / 16384.0) * (4096.0 + uSquared * (-768 + uSquared * (320.0
            - 175.0 * uSquared)));
        double bB = (uSquared / 1024.0) * (256.0 + uSquared * (-128.0 + uSquared * (74.0
            - 47.0 * uSquared)));
        double cC = (f / 16.0) * cosSqAlpha * (4.0 + f * (4.0 - 3.0 * cosSqAlpha));
        double cos2SMSq = cos2SM * cos2SM;
        deltaSigma = bB * sinSigma * (cos2SM + (bB / 4.0) * (cosSigma * (-1.0 + 2.0 * cos2SMSq)
            - (bB / 6.0) * cos2SM * (-3.0 + 4.0 * sinSigma * sinSigma) * (-3.0
            + 4.0 * cos2SMSq)));

        lambda = l + (1.0 - cC) * f * sinAlpha * (sigma + cC * sinSigma * (cos2SM
            + cC * cosSigma * (-1.0 + 2.0 * cos2SM * cos2SM)));

        double delta = (lambda - lambdaOrig) / lambda;
        if (Math.abs(delta) < 1.0e-12) {
            break;
        }
    }

    float mDistance, mInitialBearing, mFinalBearing;
    mDistance = (float) (b * aA * (sigma - deltaSigma));
    float initialBearing = (float) Math.atan2(cosU2 * sinLambda,
        cosU1 * sinU2 - sinU1 * cosU2 * cosLambda);
    initialBearing = (float) (initialBearing * (180.0 / Math.PI));
    mInitialBearing = initialBearing;
    float finalBearing = (float) Math.atan2(cosU1 * sinLambda,
        -sinU1 * cosU2 + cosU1 * sinU2 * cosLambda);
    finalBearing = (float) (finalBearing * (180.0 / Math.PI));
    mFinalBearing = finalBearing;

    return new double[] { mDistance, mInitialBearing, mFinalBearing };
}
```

Here is an example usage.
According to a few sources, the distance from *New York City* to *Los Angeles* is approximately, 3,934 km.

```java
double[] nyc = { 40.712778, -74.006111 };
double[] la = { 34.05, -118.25 };
double[] x = computeDistanceAndBearing(nyc[0], nyc[1], la[0], la[1]);
```

Output

```
[3945043.75, -86.26732635498047, -114.04286193847656]
```